# Create barcode reader using AJAX in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, barcode

I'm trying to build an application using php. in "stock_out.php", i wanna create a form that include two barcodes. I have 8 fields. (1)Effectivedate,(2)Partnumber,(3)Description1,(4)Description2,(5)NPK,(6)Nama,(7)QtyOut,(8)Reason. I wanna using barcode-reader in "Partnumber" and "NPK".
I have some problems:
1. When i press enter, it's respon for button submit.
2. Actually, when i press enter in Partnumber, i want show details data in "description1" and "description2". As well as in NPK, i want show details data in "nama"
3. In the end of form, i still want to submit this form into database.
I'm newbie in AJAX, so i still don't know how to implementation AJAX in PHP. This is my code, I am grateful for the help

```
<html><body>
<div id="outerContainer">
    <?php include("headerFile.html"); ?>
    <?php include("navigationFile.html"); ?>
    <div id="bodyContainer">
        <div id="pageBodyTitle"> Stock Out </div> <br>
        <form id="formSearch" name="formSearch" method="post" action="proses_out.php" onSubmit="return cek_data();">
        <table id="messageTable">
            <tr>
                <td class="heading"> Effective Date </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="inputField" name="tgl" type="text" readonly  value="<?php echo $_POST['tgl']?>" tabindex="1"/>
                    <script language='JavaScript'>new tcal ({'formname': 'formSearch','controlname': 'tgl'});</script>
                </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading"> Part Number </td>
                <td><input type='text' name='txtItem' id='txtItem' size="20" class="inputField" value='<?php echo $item;?>' tabindex="2" />
                <img src='search.ico' onClick='open_win_item()'> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading">Description1</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='txtDesc1' id='txtDesc1' size="50" value='<?php echo $desc1;?>'  readonly /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading">Description2</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='txtDesc2' id='txtDesc2' size="50" value='<?php echo $desc2;?>'  readonly /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading"> NPK </td>
                <td><input type='text' name='txtNpk' id='txtNpk' size="20" maxlength="5" class="inputField" value='<?php echo $tr_no;?>' tabindex="3" />
                    <img src='search.ico' onClick='open_win_npk()'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading">Nama</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='txtName' id='txtName' size="30" value='<?php echo $nama;?>' readonly /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading"> Qty Out </td>
                <td><input type='text' name='txtQty' id='txtQty' size="5" class="inputField" tabindex="4"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading"> Reason </td>                   
                <td><select class="inputField" name="choose" id="choose" value="" tabindex="5">
                <?php
                include "/class/connect_SQL.class.php";
                $sql = "select reason_code from Inv_reason_master";
                $query = mssql_query($sql);
                    while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($query)) 
                    {
                        $coba = $row['reason_code'];
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $coba; ?>"><?php echo $coba;?></option>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save" class="formButton2" tabindex="6"/>
                    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Cancel" class="formButton2" tabindex="7"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET["message"]) and  $_GET["message"]='save')
        {
            echo "<script language=\"javascript\"> alert('Data Tersimpan!') </script>";
        }
    ?>
    <?php include("footerFile.html"); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: See this link to learn ajax in php http://www.bennadel.com/resources/presentations/jquery/demo21/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/capture-all-of-the-forms-data-and-submit-it-to-a-php-script-jquery-ajax-post

Comment: it's not duplicate, that's just submit form ...
i can submit all field into database but i can't implementation in barcode-reader.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to prevent the response of the "Enter"-key. If you are using jquery in your project you can prevent it with this code:

```
$(function() {

    $("form").bind("keypress", function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) return false;
      });

});
```

To bind Enter key to "Part number" field instead you could try this:

```
$('#txtItem').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('Enter is pressed in part number');
    }
});
```